# go-fiber BodyParser "converter not found for struct structName"

Tags: json, struct, body-parser, goland, go-fiber

I'm trying to convert my current Rest API from Express.js to GO using fiber, so I am a bit new to golang, i want to parse nested JSON to nested structure in request body, I even tried the same example on github [go-fiber example](https://github.com/gofiber/fiber/issues/371#issuecomment-627775238), but I'm getting the error **"schema: converter not found for User"**

here is the example:

```
type User struct {
  FName string
  LName string
}

type respData struct {
  User
  Address
  Cart
}
respStruct := respData{}
err := c.BodyParser(&respStruct)
```